# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TableRow.addView(android.view.View)'

Tags: java, android, android-layout, facebook-audience-network

Hello guys i am here with this problem when i try to add facebook audience network to my application it crashes right away getting this error can anyone please help me with that ?

```js
2020-11-11 09:01:22.946 28765-28765/com.amongushowtoplay.com E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.amongushowtoplay.com, PID: 28765
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.amongushowtoplay.com/com.amongushowtoplay.com.PTPlayer}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3334)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3473)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7519)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
        at com.amongushowtoplay.com.PTPlayer.onCreate(PTPlayer.java:91)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3309)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3473) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2067) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7519) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

Comment: can u share a little bit of your code? with exception we only understand what is going wrong but we cannot see what u did

Comment: please send your code.

Comment: Try initializing your LinearLayout